# How to update labels using selection.join in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a horizontal bar chart that gets updated when one of the radio buttons clicked. The bars get updated fine, however, the old labels seem not to be removed every time the labels get updated. Am I missing something here? it seems that the `exit` function is not working. I couldn't find examples that deal with labels.

[image]

```
    svg_bar.selectAll(".text-bar")
    .data(dataSet)
    .join(
    enter => enter
        .append("text")
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('font-size', '16px')
        .attr('font-family', 'sans-serif')
        .attr('fill', 'white')
      .call(enter => enter.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('y', (d) => yScale_h(d.clean_test) + yScale_h.bandwidth() / 2)
        .attr('x', (d) => xScale_h(d.Award) - 14)
        .text(function (d) {
          return `${d.Award} `;
        })
       ),
    update => update 
      .call(update => update.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .text(function (d) {
          return `${d.Award} `;
        })
        .attr('y', (d) => yScale_h(d.clean_test) + yScale_h.bandwidth() / 2)
        .attr('x', (d) => xScale_h(d.Award) - 14)
       ),
    exit => exit
      .call(exit => exit.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .remove()
       )
    );
```

Comment: You have an empty selection every time: there are no elements with class `text-bar` to select so there is nothing to exit (or update for that matter: everything is entered as the selection is empty). If you give the text that class when entering you should be fine.

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought that's how selection in d3 works. However, using `svg_bar.selectAll("text")` messed up other text elements (y-axis and title) in my `svg` even though I gave them distinct classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `svg_bar.selectAll(".text-bar")`, the selection is always empty and d3 will always add new elements.

If you use `svg_bar.selectAll("text")`, the selection will include all text elements of the svg, and it will change other text elements such as the y-axis and title.

One approach to select only the texts of the bars is to select with a class, such as `svg_bar.selectAll("text.bar")`. For this to work, the appended bars need to be assigned to the 'bar' class with `.classed('bar', true)`, so they selected in the next render.

```js
svg_bar.selectAll("text.bar") // Selects the texts of class "bar"
    .data(dataSet)
    .join(
    enter => enter
        .append("text")
        .classed("bar", true) // Create texts with class "bar"
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')

...
```